# How do you say "a B student" in French?

Tags: traduction

In (american) English, to describe a person who was not outstanding in school, but who wasn't failing either -- an average student if you will -- you might describe them as "a B student". How would you convey the same idea in French?

Comment: Un étudiant lambda.

Comment: Hi, bienvenue sur French Language SE. What did you find when you started to research how to say this?

Comment: @livresque "Un étudiant de catégorie B", but I don't think that they use the A, B, C, F system in France, so I'm not sure this would make much sense for a French person

Comment: You are right it makes no sense to a French person because we don't use GPA rating. So you'd have to give the equivalent in the French system of evaluation (i.e. see [here](https://www.orientation.com/articles/etudier-etranger/etats-unis/calculer-son-score-gpa/)) or if you needn't be too precise you'd just see *un étudiant juste au-dessus de la moyenne* (just above average).

Comment: unremarkable -> peu distingué

Comment: A B student is not a negative thing; it is just not remarkable. Un étudiant moyen. Voilà l'idée.

Answer (score 12):

In French a different noun for "student" would tend to be used according to the type of school attended. For students in high school or below that level the term "élève" is used the most; for students in university, the word "étudiant" is used almost uniquely. The following terms are common.

- élève moyen, étudiant moyen ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A9l%C3%A8ve+moyen%2C%C3%A9tudiant+moyen&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A9l%C3%A8ve%20moyen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A9tudiant%20moyen%3B%2Cc0))

The term "bon élève" is used a lot also, but "bon étudiant" is not used much. ([bon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bon+%C3%A9l%C3%A8ve%2Cbon+%C3%A9tudiant&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbon%20%C3%A9l%C3%A8ve%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbon%20%C3%A9tudiant%3B%2Cc0)).

Comment: By the by, in Canadian French one often hears "élève" only up to about Grade 8, and "étudiant" already in high school, just as a curiosity.

Comment: In France, as far as I know, it's « élève » until the baccaulauréat and/or « classe prépa ». For instance, you'd be « élève au collège », « élève au lycée », « élève en math spé ». And « ancien élève de l'école normale » is very common. But you'd say « étudiant en Sorbonne ».

Comment: They're not look for the word for student - but rather the diferentiation between a great student and a good one

Answer (score 6):

France and US grading systems are somewhat different in both their range and linearity.

As you described B as "average", that might match *un étudiant/élève<sup>1</sup> de niveau **passable*** (enough to pass). This level applies to students with a grade between 10 and 12 or that might match a ***bon élève*** if the B level is considered to match the ***assez bien*** French one.

After reading all the comments, I believe the closest expression would be ***un assez bon élève***.

Here is a chart where I try to match France and US gradings assuming B is *passable*<sup>2</sup> (third column) or, more likely, ***assez bien***<sup>2</sup> (last column):

| France | Meaning<sup>1</sup> | US | US<sup>2</sup> |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `18-20` | Très bien + Félicitations | `A+` | `A+` |
| `16-18` | Très bien | `A+` | `A` |
| `14-16` | Bien | `A` | `B+` |
| **`12-14`** | Assez bien | `B+` | **`B`** |
| **`10-12`** | Passable | **`B`** | `C` |
| `10` | Moyenne | `C` | `C` |
| `8-10` | Insuffisant | `D/C-` | `D/C-` |
| `0-8` | Très insuffisant | `F` | `F` |

Sources:

1. [French and American grading equivalency for transcripts: Why is it so hard to convert French grades into American grades (and vice versa)? - Charles Eddy](https://ceddytraductions.fr/articles/2020-03-18_translating-grades_US-and-French-Systems.shtml)

[image]

2. [Ammon & Rousseau](https://www.ammon-rousseau.com/wp-content/uploads/French-Vs-US-Grading-System.pdf)

[image]

3. [Studying in France](https://www.studying-in-france.org/french-grading-system/)

[image]

4. [Université Paris 10 - ECTS](https://web.archive.org/web/20140113104131/http://www.u-paris10.fr/international/systeme-ects-2988.kjsp)

[image]

<sup>1</sup> In France, we use *élève* for a student attending a primary school (*écolier*), a secondary school (*collège*: *collégien*, *lycée*: *lycéen*). Students attending a University are called *étudiants*. Students from *[grandes écoles](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande_%C3%A9cole)* (Polytechnique, ENA,  Saint Cyr, Centrale, Mines, Pons, Normale sup...) are also often still called *élèves*.

<sup>2</sup> Note that on the meaning of a French grade might substantially vary depending on the level (primary, secondary, university, *grandes écoles*...), the school, the teacher, the period, the discipline or the kind of exam. The trend is often reported to be towards higher and higher scores for a similar level, and marks that were exceptional several decades ago tend to become commonplace.

Comment: No, *passable* is just above the failure threshold. The meaning remains close to the etymology: a student is *passable* if the best you can say about them is that they're passing. A B student is not great, but better than just passing. I think *passable* matches very closely to C.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Yes, that's the interpretation I stated in my last sentence. Both the French and US grading systems are subjective but *passable* is nevertheless between 10 and 12 so IMHO wider than "just above threshold". The OP told a B student is neither outstanding nor failing, the reason why I picked the pessimistic choice.

Comment: The expression “a C student” also exists. Both a B student and a C student are neither outstanding nor failing, but a C student is just barely passing whereas a B student is comfortably passing.

Comment: Yes, that's the definition I can find [here](https://registrar.unc.edu/academic-services/grades/explanation-of-grading-system/): *B: Strong performance demonstrating a high level of attainment for a student at a given stage of development. The B grade states that the student has shown solid promise in the aspect of the discipline under study.* The issue with *average* is it means either the middle mark of the possible grades (fixed) or the average of the actual students grades (variable).

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Answer updated with both interpretations.

Comment: A B student is “average” in the sense of unremarkable, rather than in some numerical sense. It's really similar to how in French « un étudiant moyen » ne veut pas dire « un étudiant qui a la moyenne ».

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Tu as certainement raison mais ce qui doit me tromper, c'est que l'anglais reprend la même terminologie que celles des notes.

Comment: J'ai entendu dire « on est 8 [sur 20] » pour indiquer un problème en général donc est-ce que ça se dit, « on est 10 » pour exprimer cette idée de moyenne ?  Sinon 20/20 c'est pour la prof, je plussoie :)

Comment: This fails to capture the fact that a 8/20 can be considered pretty good in some schools and some subjects. I remember days (in the 1980s) when no-one in math class had over 10 and a 9 was "genius level".

Comment: @PatrickT I do remember indeed. It would be interesting to know what average grading this year's *baccalauréat général* students (stunning 97.6% success rate) would have got eighty years ago if  they had taken the *certificat d'études primaires* exam...

Comment: @livresque Je ne crois pas avoir entendu *on est 8 [sur 20]* mais plutôt *on est des 8 [sur 20]*, probablement.

Comment: These charts do not deal with the issue of the meaning of the English. The idiom, a B student means not an A student. But more than just passing.

Comment: @Lambie I posted the charts to show how the US grades compare to French ones. A fact is there is no French idiom I'm aware of which uses a grade (except maybe *un zéro*). After reading all the comments, I believe the closest expression would be *un assez bon élève*.

Comment: @jlliagre, Indeed. Casual evidence: When I was in « terminale » we used my friend's brother's math notes from his « première »: same school, just 4 years between us, the year 1988. If that rate of decline persisted beyond, the current baccalauréat would be equivalent to our kindergarten. Ah ah! ;-(

Answer (score 4):

How you render an "B student" in French depends to what purpose you need to use the phrase.

- If it is to be used in a casual manner and do not need to be accurate you could say:

  - - *un élève/étudiant tout à fait moyen*

which is a phrase teachers and lecturers would use when talking about a student who is just above average (which is what a B student is).

- If you need the phrase for a more formal situation, for instance for a cover letter or to apply to a French university then you might have to give a numerical rating equivalent using a converting table (as the one you can see [there](https://www.orientation.com/articles/etudier-etranger/etats-unis/calculer-son-score-gpa/)). But in fact if you apply for a French university they will ask you for a transcript of grades from the previous academic year (whether in high school or as an undergraduate).

Note that this applies to France, in other French speaking countries they might express this differently.

Answer (score 2):

Un étudiant *ordinaire*, ...*comme un autre*.

Comment: *De deuxième plan* me semble péjoratif et trop fort (est-ce [_B_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/B#Etymology_3) ou *B-grade*).

Comment: Ça me paraît trop général. Pour faire allusion aux résultats scolaires, on dirait plutôt « peu remarquable ».

Comment: It's definitely not passable. ordinaire might work.